# What is the best practice of the directory Structure Of Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, web-inf

For the WEB-INF folder, it will only store the files that are not accessible to the public. So it will be only index.html stay outside of the WEB-INF folder? For example, like the login and register jsp file should stay inside or outside the WEB-INF folder?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the WEB-INF content will not be accessible when the web is deployed. Commonly this folder store web **low level settings**. Also when the app is deployed (classic war on tomcat) this folder WEB-INF **has a folder called lib** with all the jar libraries.

Any other static asset like, html, css, font, js, etc should be outside of **WEB-INF**

Just the dynamic content like .jsp should be inside  of **WEB-INF**

Take a look to this [maven structure](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/):

[image]

or this in which we can see the classic [web.xml](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

[image]

or this with [spring-boot](https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jsp)

```
./pom.xml
./src
./src/main
./src/main/webapp
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
./src/main/resources
./src/main/resources/application.properties
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/com
./src/main/java/com/
./src/main/java/com/examples
./src/main/java/com/examples/spring
./src/main/java/com/examples/spring/springbootjsp
./src/main/java/com/examples/spring/springbootjsp/controllers
./src/main/java/com/examples/spring/springbootjsp/controllers/HelloController.java
./src/main/java/com/examples/spring/springbootjsp/SpringBootJspApplication.java
```

I advice you:

- Use a maven structure for your java web app
- Use spring

Comment: thanks for the comment. Really helpful. Actually I am new to the web development, still a newbie. May I ask how should I use spring in my web application?

Comment: Yes, you should.  I have another advice. Java and other server side languages (c#, php, python, etc) are not used anymore for web development. They are used to develop microservices or rest apis. Today, the web development is reduced to the wel known: react, angular and vue. If your priority is be ready for a job, I advice to use java for microservices, not for web development, or at least just to learn. Also check this https://github.com/open-source-education/junior-software-developer